# Spring Data JPA filter set of enum values with @query or by function name

Tags: java, sql, jpa, enums, spring-data-jpa

I have a set of enums as an attribute in MyClass (which is an Entity) and want to filter the string values of the enum either with @Query or with the JPA function name querying (dont know the proper name for it...) .

My Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ONE("First string value"),
    TWO("Second string value"),
    THREE("Third string value");

    private MyEnum (String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
    private final String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Declaration of the Set of Enums in the MyClass-Entity

```
@Size(min=1)
@ElementCollection (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<MyEnum> myenums;
```

The table it creates:

```
create table myclass_myenums (myclass_id bigint not null, myenum varchar(255));
```

@Query attempt in my Repository.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from mytable t " +
            " left join myclass_myenums e ON e.myclass_id= t.id " +
            " WHERE " +
            " e.myenum LIKE CONCAT('%',:filtertext,'%') " 
            , nativeQuery = true)
    List<RisikoEntity> findbyFilter(@Param("filtertext") String filtertext);
```

This works, the problem is though, it filters on the Strings "ONE", "TWO", "THREE" and not on "First string value", "Second ..." and so on.

---

Alternative attempt with  the function-name thing attempt in my Repository:

```
List<MyClass> findByMyenumsContainsIgnoreCase(String filterstring)

---> Error: "Parameter value [%First%] did not match expected type [path.to.MyEnum (n/a)]"
```

Second attempt:

```
List<MyClass> findByMyenums_NameContainsIgnoreCase(String filterstring)

--> Error: "Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null] of basic type"
```

What am I doing wrong?

1. How can I filter the actual enum string-values in the first solution?
2. How can I filter sets of enum with the JPA function name thing?

Comment: Your enum code does not seem to compile.  You must be having other field there to set your description,

Comment: How can JOIN work in your query if you don't have `join_id` in the table description for your enum, where you have `myclass_id`?

Comment: sorry, I forgot the constructor in the example, is that what you meant? And you are correct, I didnt want to give all of my actual code, so I had to rename some stuff for the MCVE, i edited it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, here enum is not a string where like expect string expression

Comment: Yes, constructor

Comment: You can try @Query attempt by saving enum value in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JPA 2.1, you may try to use its `@Converter` annotation as [suggested here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa#converter) but this can create significant overhead as the converted String value will have to be stored in your entity:

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MyEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyEnum, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(MyEnum myEnum) {
        if (myEnum == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return myEnum.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public MyEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String code) {
        if (code == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return Stream.of(MyEnum.values())
          .filter(m -> m.toString().equals(code))
          .findFirst()
          .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still filters to "ONE" instead of "First string value" - I also tried adding @Convert (converter = MyEnumConverter.class) to the Entity-field in case the autoApply wouldnt work, but same result :/

Comment: Figured it out - I needed to replace @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) with @Convert (btw, the auto-apply didn't work for some reason). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well I would say that this is not possible because JPA does not persist the `name` String of the enum but rather the actual name of the enum.

So your Database should contain *ONE* or *TWO* instead of *First string value* or *Second string value* inside `myenum` column.

The only way to solve this is to first filter the enum by code and then find by that enum

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I would have to left join another table on ONE / TWO / THREE with the "First string value" in a second column and filter on that column for the @Query solution?

Comment: You could do that yes, create a table that contains your enum